# Clipping Effect in Toon Boom Harmony 15.0

Tags: 2d, clipping

I want to do similar effect like this tutorial [Masking Effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXsrk9vgptI). The tutorial using Toon Boom Studio 8, I'm using Toon Boom Harmony 15 and can't seem to find the Cliiping Effect they use in tutorial. Not even from Node View. Any advice to do the same effect ??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use the same effect using Cutter. Connect the cutter to the drawing, and fill the matte field with new layer for masking.
Works like a charm!

Documentation : [Cutter](https://docs.toonboom.com/help/harmony-12/premium-network/Content/_CORE/_Workflow/031_Effects/056_H2_Cutter.html?Highlight=CUTTER)

[image]